# OpenVPN server in Windows Server to share three different networks to clients

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, network-share, nic

I am relatively new with OpenVPN, but I am able to create an OpenVPN Server on a Windows Server, and connect a client to it.

The Windows Server is connected with three NICs:

```
NIC1 - 16.0.0.0/21 (NS: 16.0.5.1, 16.0.5.2)
NIC2 - 15.0.0.0/21 (NS: 15.0.3.100, 15.0.3.101)
NIC3 - 192.168.1.0/23 (NS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)
```

But whenever my client connects to the OpenVPN server, the client do not have internet connection, nor any site reachable, including within the local network.

The goal is for connecting clients to access the subnetworks 16.0.0.0/21, 15.0.0.0/21, and 192.168.1.0/23
The connecting clients can use 15.0.3.101 for all the DNS Lookup.

Here is my server.ovpn

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca "D:\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "D:\\config\\server.crt"
key "D:\\config\\server.key"
dh "D:\\config\\dh2048.pem"
topology subnet
server 192.168.250.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Here is my client.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 192.168.1.52 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert user.crt
key user.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
```

Server is 192.168.250.1, and when the client connects it gets an IP address of 192.168.250.2

Once connected, the client can't even show 192.168.250.1 IIS default page.

I haven't done any routing as I do not know how to do it.

UPDATE:

**I tried putting this to the server.ovpn but it didn't work**

```
push "route 16.0.0.0 255.255.248.0 192.168.250.1 1"
push "route 15.0.0.0 255.255.248.0 192.168.250.1 1"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.254.0 192.168.250.1 1"
```

Comment: You might want to try and start the Openvpnclient as admin (if your on windows), you might have an issue with user permissions not able to add routes. This would be visible in the log output of the client.

Comment: I just tried running the openVPN client as an Admin, and connected to the openVPN server, but same issue persists. @DennisNolte